# Save Pdf in Zip with MemoryStream

Tags: c#, pdf, zip, itext

I try the save multiples files pdf in zip but I can't, can somebody can help me?

```
using (MemoryStream memorystream = new MemoryStream())
{
    string zip = @"C:\Temp\ZipFile.zip";
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memorystream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            ZipArchiveEntry file = archive.CreateEntry(string.Format("Test{0}.pdf", i), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            using (Stream stream = file.Open())
            {
                Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memorystream);
                document.Open();
                //
                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(7);
                Font fdefault = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
                table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Container", fdefault));
                table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Code", fdefault));
                table.AddCell(new Paragraph("ITEM", fdefault));
                table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Reference", fdefault));
                table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Description", fdefault));
                table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Size", fdefault));
                table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Quantity", fdefault));
                document.Add(table);
                document.Close();
                writer.Close();
                memorystream.Close();
           }
        }
    }
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(zip, FileMode.Create))
    {
        memorystream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        memorystream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }    
}
```

I do it that with ExcelPackage and work but this don't work, I don't know the problem. I would appreciate if anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: You haven't told us *anything* about the way in which it doesn't work. What goes wrong? Does it compile? Does it throw an exception? Does it generate a zip file which has errors? Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 1):

You've got two fatal flaws.

First, you are binding the `PdfWriter` to the zip's `MemoryStream` instead of the `Stream` that you are getting back from `ZipArchiveEntry.Open()`. So change this line:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memorystream);
```

To this:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
```

Second but related to the first, you are closing the zip's `MemoryStream` inside of the for loop. Just kill off the line:

```
memorystream.Close();
```

Putting that all together and switching over to the preferred `using` pattern you get this:

```
using (var zipMemorystream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipMemorystream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var file = archive.CreateEntry(string.Format("Test{0}.pdf", i), CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            using (Stream stream = file.Open( ))
            {
                using( var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30) )
                {
                    using( var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream))
                    {
                        document.Open();
                        //
                        var table = new PdfPTable(7);
                        var fdefault = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
                        table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Container", fdefault));
                        table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Code", fdefault));
                        table.AddCell(new Paragraph("ITEM", fdefault));
                        table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Reference", fdefault));
                        table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Description", fdefault));
                        table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Size", fdefault));
                        table.AddCell(new Paragraph("Quantity", fdefault));
                        document.Add(table);
                        document.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    string zip = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "ZipFile.zip");
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(zip, FileMode.Create))
    {
        zipMemorystream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        zipMemorystream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```